# scala/java get json value using dot pattern

Tags: java, json, scala

I am using java/scala and I have a json something like

```
 {
    "a":{
        "b1":"x",
        "b2":"x2"
    },
    "c":{
        "d1":"y",
        "d2":"y2"
    }
 }
```

I would like to get the value using something like

```
"a.b1" gives me x
"c.d1" gives me y
```

It doesn't have to be exactly as mentioned, even something like

```
("a").("b1) = x or
("a")[1].("b1") //for arrays
```

Any variations like this will work

Comment: Of course you need to indicate which JSON lib

Comment: I can use any json lib that can provide the functionality

Comment: So first have a look at the doc of the various lib

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/):

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.parser._

case class MyData(a: Map[String, String], c: Map[String, String])
implicit val myDataDecoder: Decoder[MyData] = deriveDecoder

val someJson: String = """{
    "a":{
        "b1":"x",
        "b2":"x2"
    },
    "c":{
        "d1":"y",
        "d2":"y2"
    }
 }"""

// decode returns an Either, so we call merge/asInstanceOf to get the underlying instance
val parsedData = decode[MyData](someJson).merge.asInstanceOf[MyData]

// Now we can access the data as needed
parsedData.a.get("b1").get // "x"
```

You can adjust the `MyData` case class as needed to match your data structure.

Working example [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/adrice727/AnbIBXAcRaSzsnCvn3e7QQ).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jsonpath. It does exactly what I wanted.